# Rails display a list of has_and_belongs_to_many features for a given project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between client "projects" and "features" that they selected through a collection_checkbox administered through a join table called projects_features.

So: each user is able to create projects, and these projects have features that they select and save using a checkbox list - awesome.

I am now trying to edit the show view when the customer wants to take a look at his project, and want to display a list of features his particular project has. How would you do this? Could I do it through a loop displaying from the table or would I need to store the matching features into an array and then display them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features are already an attribute of the project, so you can do in the view something like the following...

```
<h4>Features</h4>

<% @project.features.each do |feature| %>
  <%= feature.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

This is very simple but you can enhance by using a HTML table or other presentation style.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you! Man, still trying to wrap my mind around these associations! Thanks again :)